# Using the ALT key in Windows with Parallels

Tags: parallels-desktop, windows

I need Windows for my development environment on my Mac. I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> a lot in this software. I can't do this on my Mac. Is there a way to send the Alt key presses to the virtual machine?

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> shows the Accessibility Utility Manager. Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> just types an "s". At work on Windows XP, neither of these behaviors happen.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't fully understand your question. Does the Alt key not work in Parallels? It works in the distributions I have seen...

On a Mac, alt and option are one in the same for a key...

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the option for switching alt and cmd. The mapping should be: alt=option, cmd=windows.

Comment: Oh... I'll try that.

Comment: I'll have to remember slightly different keyboard mappings (from my Windows machine at work), but it seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the desired effect by holding down the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd> keys, then releasing just the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key to use the <kbd>alt</kbd> function.

Hurrah! No editing keyboard preferences required. Hope this helps someone else too.

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution is to use the right Alt not the left Alt on the keyboard. For unknown reasons that does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Go in to preferences on Parallels and add mappings individually for each letter combo of <kbd>alt</kbd> and a letter. <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> maps to <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> maps to <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> etc for all key combos that involve <kbd>alt</kbd>.  Time consuming but it appears to work so far.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the option key - I just used it on the Windows 8 Dev Preview as well as Windows 7 using VMWare Fusion 4. See picture below for detail of option key:

[image: option key]

Comment: It is these two particular keystrokes that don't work. I think the key strokes are being send to the OS first instead of the application like a dedicated Windows install may do it. (just guessing based on behavior). At this point I have basically given up and just swear every time I need to use the key combination.

Comment: Do you have VMware Tools installed on the VM?

Comment: Yes. Recently I created a brand new VM (because of stupidity on my part ruining and old one). I have the same problem. My guess is listed above.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the "Optimize modifier keys for games" option; does it help you?

[Problems with Ctrl, Alt, Cmd, Shift and other modifiers in games](http://kb.parallels.com/7072)

(I want to use the option, but don't see it in my configuration panels...)

Oh, it's moved to the [Advanced pane](http://download.parallels.com/desktop/v6/docs/en/Parallels_Desktop_Users_Guide/31983.htm).

Comment: I have tried that and it doesn't work. It seems like Windows captures the event and doesn't pass it along to the active software.

Answer (score 0):

I just set one map: `option` to `Alt`, and it works.